# If a husband and wife get divorced before the marriage was consummated, is it possible to remarry?

Tags: nikah, sex, talaq

If a husband and wife get divorced before the marriage was consummated, although they made love but didn't have intercourse, is it possible to remarry?

Comment: How can you divorce if you aren't married?

Comment: @Kilise they are married, but marriage was not consummated at the time of divorce!

Comment: do you think that if there was no consummation, it can be harder to remarry than if it would be consummated? if so - why?

Answer (score 2):

In Shia views, it's okay to remarry your wife but if you divorce her for third time, remarry is on the condition of the woman marry and divorce another man.

- [Iran's Ruling on Islamic marriage and divorce](http://www.dadsetani.ir/Portals/dadsetani.ir/PaperAttch/958.htm)

Comment: Oh dear mate, what you illustrated in short looks an appropriate brief answer (although it would be nicer if you expand it to somehow. Anyhow, I appreciate your helpful answer (especially for mentioning the source which was useful for me).

Answer (score 1):

For sure, In Islam, divorced couples can get back to each others but there are some rules to take in account.

Divorce has three types:

- Talaq raj3i: the one happens when a husband says it to his wife for the first time, in this case, she wait at their home  for 3 months, within which he can get her back anytime, she is still considered his wife until the end of the specific period.
  some references and more explanation is in the [here](http://myummah.co.za/site/2008/04/29/types-of-divorce/). reference from quran: قول الله تعالى: ﴿ وَالْمُطَلَّقَاتُ يَتَرَبَّصْنَ بِأَنفُسِهِنَّ ثَلَاثَةَ قُرُوءٍ ﴾(البقرة:228) إلى قوله: ﴿ وَبُعُولَتُهُنَّ أَحَقُّ بِرَدِّهِنَّ فِي ذَلِكَ إِنْ أَرَادُوا إِصْلاحًا﴾(البقرة: 228)
- Talaq ba2en baynona soghra: if the 3 months period passed (or a pregnancy is finished) without they get back to each others, they have to leave each others, and can get back only by a new marriage contract.
- Talaq ba2en baynona kobra: in the case, two husbands were divorced for the third time, they can not get married again unless the wife got married with someone else and then got divorced for some reason. 
  له تعالى: ﴿ فَإِنْ طَلَّقَهَا فَلَا تَحِلُّ لَهُ مِنْ بَعْدُ حَتَّى تَنكِحَ زَوْجًا غَيْرَهُ ﴾ (البقرة:230)

Anyway, you will find [here](http://myummah.co.za/site/2008/04/29/types-of-divorce/) more comprehensive details.

[This](http://www.al-eman.com/%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%83%D8%AA%D8%A8/%D9%85%D9%88%D8%B3%D9%88%D8%B9%D8%A9%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%81%D9%82%D9%87%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A5%D8%B3%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85%D9%8A/%D8%A3%D8%AD%D9%88%D8%A7%D9%84%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B7%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%82%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A8%D8%A7%D8%A6%D9%86%20%D8%A8%D9%8A%D9%86%D9%88%D9%86%D8%A9%20%D8%B5%D8%BA%D8%B1%D9%89:/i582&d920424&c&p1) is also one of my references but in arabic